# Comparar métodos de lenguajes

Tags: web

**Si yo sé más avanzandamente Javascript** y por ende lo entiendo mejor que otros lenguajes, **existe alguna web o programa** que me dé los métodos **parecidos de otros lenguajes**? Me explico:

**En `javascript` existe el `typeof` , para verificar el tipo, ejemplo:**

```
var a = '';
if(typeof a == 'undefined') console.log('No puede ser indefinido');
```

Y por ejemplo para **php**, necesitaría una **web para ver los métodos parecidos**, osea cual es el método `typeof` **pero en `PHP`**?, **y así con cualquier método en cualquier lenguaje de programación**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respuesta rápida: **NO**.

Respuesta menos rápida:

Cuando un programador hace un programa en un lenguaje, normalmente sabe usar dicho lenguaje. Como comentas, hay ocasiones que somos más familiares con un lenguaje y requerimos hacerlo en otro. Pero, los lenguajes no son *lo mismo*, cada uno fue diseñado con ciertos objetivos en mente. Con el propósito de mejorar lo existente hasta su creación.

Hay ocasiones, cuando los lenguajes tienen ámbitos similares, y es cuando, en buscar más usuarios, se escriben guías "Lenguaje X para programadores de G".

Lo más común, es cuando encuentras la necesidad, puedes buscar "*funcionalidadX* en *nuevo lenguaje*", usando tu ejemplo, buscar "typeof en PHP" y generalmente encuentras bastantes ayudas.